# Show blocks at a specific URL

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm trying to move some Blocks to a different Page.  None of the Blocks are defined in a region. They are specified to display on every Page.

In reality, they show up on only one Page. I tried deleting that Page, and when I navigate to the URL of that page, the Blocks still show up, along with the message that this page does not exist. I made a new Page, and I can't figure out how to get those Blocks to display on the new Page. I've been looking into this for weeks, and I just can't figure it out.

Any suggestions in this matter?

Comment: Well, I anticipate you have the source code in front of you. If you can't find it in the back-end (structure/blocks, panels, views, displays), it's probably done programmatically within custom modules/the theme. As there are plenty possible locations which even vary between Drupal 7 and 8, I fear you're on your own finding it first, or asking someone to help you review your code base. Surely out of the scope of what we can do at Drupal Answers without a lot of guesswork.

Comment: Thank you, @MarioSteinitz.  I have looked at the theme code.  I did a search for the URL in the whole folder, and I found nothing.  It leads me to believe that there is some setting in the database that is controlling its visibility.

Comment: Probably it's connected to the node ID, URL aliases (which you'd find in the database), ... - Try finding the block ID and check if it is hard-coded somewhere, locate probably used templates (e.g., by enabling theme debugging in Drupal 8, or searching for specific HTML/CSS classes), check according preprocess hooks in the theme or custom modules. That's what I'd try first having the source code in front of me. Yet, all things that are hard to help you with without access to the sources.

Comment: Cowards down vote a question without providing any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  There is a module called [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) installed on the website, and, as I originally suspected, this module looks at the path and modifies (or "reacts") to the path when the user navigates to it.

I also had problems adding and modifying blocks to the regions available in the Context editor.  You have to select the item on the right side first, and then click on the +Add button on the left side in the region you want to add the block to.

After so many weeks, this is such a relief to be able to find out.  I sincerely hope that I do not have such issues again.  Thank you again, so much, for your help in all of this.  I know it doesn't seem like you helped much, but I think by just talking it out a little bit more, I was able to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: glad you figured it out ... content was going to be my next suggestion actually !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in **Drupal 7** you will need to check the block visibility settings for that block

1. `structure > block`
2. in the list find the block in question and click configure
3. change the visibility settings

[image]

On a default installation there are visility settings per URL / per content type / per role / per user but many more can be added by contributed modules.

On **Drupal 8** something similar can be found on `structure > block layout`

[image]

Comment: The Blocks are being displayed at the URL even though this setting is blank.  (All pages except those listed.)  I tried this earlier, and I did get some results, but it just wasn't what I need.

Comment: Then you need to share more information about your setup. The procedure above is the most widely used way to put a block on a specific URL.  Of course some module can do such thing programmatically but we can't guess which module might be doing this.

Comment: That's what's so frustrating about this whole problem.  If the developer had followed "widely used" practices, I probably would not be in this situation.

Comment: There’s probably a good technical reason context was installed in drupal 7. I believe on larger sites or sites with lots of blocks it improved performance instead of use the regular block admin.

Comment: Well, that is good to know, @Kevin.